# C - Displaying pointer content. Difference between str and int

Tags: c, pointers

I am playing around with various pointer examples and have a rather basic question.

Ignore how things are being manipulated and it is just various ways to obtain a better understanding.

The question pertains to the output of the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sampleForPosting();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int size = 5;
    char* strVar;
    strVar = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);

    int* intVar;
    intVar = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    *(strVar + 0) = '1';
    *(strVar + 1) = '2';
    *(strVar + 2) = '3';
    *(strVar + 3) = '4';
    *(strVar + 4) = '\0';

    *(intVar + 0) = 1;
    *(intVar + 1) = 2;
    *(intVar + 2) = 3;
    *(intVar + 3) = 4;

    printf("\n");
    printf("strVar        : %s\n", strVar); /// %s means to print out until \0 is reached

    printf("\n");
    printf("intVar        : %d\n", intVar);

}
```

***Output :***

```
strVar        : 1234
intVar        : 13193920
```

***Questions :***

When printing out the content of the string pointer it prints out the actual string.
When printing out the content of the int pointer it prints out the address where the number resides.

Why the different behavior?
Is the behavior dictated by the printf arguments %s or %n?

Comment: Are you expecting an array of `int`s to be treated the same as a NUL-terminated array of `char`s?

Comment: I actually get a compilation warning, that %d expects type int, but the value is actually of type  int *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` prints a string, to print a string you must pass the address of the first character and it reads until `\0` as your said.

`%d` prints an integer, to print an integer you need to pass an integer, but you are passing a pointer as parameter.

Since `intVar` is a pointer it prints the address. If you want to print the number, you have to use `*intVar` or `*(intVar + x)`.

```c
printf("intVar        : %d\n", *intVar);
```

See the [printf man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html):

> The format string is composed of [...] **conversion specifications**, each of which results in fetching zero or more subsequent arguments.  Each conversion specification is introduced by the character `%`, and ends with a **conversion specifier**.

And for the Conversion specifiers:

> A character that specifies the **type of conversion** to be applied.  The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> **d**, **i**   The int argument is converted to **signed decimal** notation
>
> **s**      [...] the `const char *` argument is
>                 expected to be a pointer to an array of character type
>                 (pointer to a string)
>
> **p**      The `void *` pointer argument is printed in hexadecimal (as if by %#x or %#lx).

Comment: Based on your answer it is the arguments which dictates the behavior, correct?

Comment: `%d` is a format flag. The format flag dictates how the argument is parsed by the function. `%d` parses integers. But you passed a pointer (which is a long unsigned integer). So the function will convert this pointer into an integer. If you want to print the address you can use the flag `%p` but if you want to print the value at the address `intVar` which is an integer you have to dereference the pointer to access its value using `*`.

Comment: I've edited to quote the documentation. Don't hesitate to check the [printf man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) to understand how the formating works

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to compile your code:

```
 warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
```

The compile shows you the warning about the format type.

When you use `%s` it means you talk with the compiler: `Hey, compiler, help me to print the string`.

When you use `%d` it means you talk with the compile: `Hey, compiler, help me to print the integer value`. So the compiler will print out the value of variable `intVar`

If you want to print the address of pointer, you should use `%p`:

```
printf("intVar        : %p\n", intVar);
```

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2019 and there were no warnings.  Also, the objective is more geared toward why the difference in behavior.

Comment: Thanks, your edits makes sense and helped address the main questions.

Comment: VS2019 does give a warning: "warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int *'"